# Android Fragment not inflating after transaction

Tags: android, fragment, android-inflate

I've been trying to inflate a simple contentFragment after clicking on the tab from my navigation drawer. Here is my CentralView class that contains the attempt to inflate the Fragment

```
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.FragmentManager;
import android.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.support.design.widget.NavigationView;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.SubMenu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Toast;

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
public class CentralView extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Toolbar toolbar;
    private NavigationView navigationView;
    private DrawerLayout drawerLayout;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_central_view);

        toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.navigation_view);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(new NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem menuItem) {


                //Checking if the item is in checked state or not, if not make it in checked state
                if(menuItem.isChecked()) menuItem.setChecked(false);
                else menuItem.setChecked(true);

                //Closing drawer on item click
                drawerLayout.closeDrawers();

                //Check to see which item was being clicked and perform appropriate action
                switch (menuItem.getItemId()){


                    //Replacing the main content with ContentFragment Which is our Inbox View;
                    case R.id.home:
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Inbox Selected",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        ContentFragment fragment = new ContentFragment();
                        android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.frame,fragment);
                        fragmentTransaction.commit();
                        return true;
```

And here is my ContentFragment class

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

/**
 * Created by Admin on 04-06-2015.
 */
public class ContentFragment extends Fragment {

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_content_fragment,container,false);
        return v;
    }
}
```

I've searched StackOverflow and while people have had similar issues, none of the fixes worked for me. Apologies if it's out there. Here is the XML for my content Fragment as well

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="INBOX"
        android:padding="8dp"
        android:textColor="#fff"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:textSize="28sp"
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

edit: adding activity_central_view.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                                        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
                                        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                                        android:id="@+id/drawer"
                                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                                        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                                        tools:context=".CentralView">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        >
        <include
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            layout="@layout/tool_bar"/>
        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/frame"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

        </FrameLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/navigation_view"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/header"
        app:menu="@menu/drawer"/>
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Comment: Can you please add `activity_central_view.xml` to your question?

Comment: @cricket_007 added

Comment: What have you done so far to debug? Did the "Inbox Selected" toast appear? There's a lot of code that you've posted. Help people help you by narrowing down the problem.

Comment: @Da-JinC Yes the toast appears. I know that the case is executed when clicked.

Comment: Honestly, I don't see why what you have done shouldn't work

Comment: @cricket_007 I'm just as flustered as you. Every other SO question I've come across has fixes that just aren't working. Strangest thing.

Comment: Try putting a Toast or a Log statement in the Fragment

Comment: I put a toast text "debug" in the fragment and sure enough it shows when I select "inbox" @cricket_007

Comment: @cricket_007 It was an issue with my "toolbar" element. XML was bugged forcing the whole fragment and navigation to freeze up. Appreciate your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect your tool_bar layout might be having a height of match_parent.

Could you please share tool_bar file?

Comment: You were correct! My toolbar XML was bugged and the fragment was dependent on that. Was coming back to update my answer when I saw yours. Much appreciated.